# How to add "chrome-extension:" to permissions, in manifest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to set the local storage of a chrome-extension: url, in my background script using the following code

```
            chrome.tabs.create({
              active: false,
              url: chrome.runtime.getURL('/index.html')
          }, function(tab) {
              chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                  code: 'localStorage.setItem("test", "testOne");'
              }, function() {
                  chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
              });
          });
```

However I get the following error

**Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://ajhekomgfmlogkidfmfehhgpdjcgijng/subscription-prompt". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.**

To fix this I tried to modify my permissions in my manifest like this

```
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
      "activeTab",
      "notifications",
  "webNavigation",
  "tabs",
  "storage"
  ],
```

However I still get the same error, how can I fix this?

Comment: Extensions are fully isolated. You would have to implement a communication method in both extensions.

Comment: Without modifying the other extension the only way to do it is a devtools panel where you can call chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval, see Storage Area Explorer extension for an example of how it works and the source code if needed.